# How to find the reason of the "out of range" exception?

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging, exception

I'm trying to store ten values in an array with C#. If I use only single digit numbers, everything goes smoothly. However, every time I give numbers with two or more digits, I get an error that it out of bounds of the array index. I suspect that it is storing each digit separately, such as if 10 is the first number I enter, it would store 1 in the first position and 0 in the second. However, I am not sure. Is that the problem here or is it something else? How can I fix this?

(using Microsoft visual studio 2010 ultimate)

the code:

```
double[] userValues = new double[10];

for (int i=0; i < userValues.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write("Enter a value: ");
    userValues[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

an example of the errors I'm getting:

```
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10
Enter a value: 10

Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Assignment1.Program.Main(String[] args) in I:\CS2350\Assignment1\Assignment1\Program.cs:line 21
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: That code works for me.  What other code occurs after the loop?

Comment: What is the line of code at line 21?

Comment: Simply run in the the debugger (maybe enable within the menu Debug - Exceptions the CLR exception) and take a look at the line where VS2010 stops.

Answer (score 1):

Exception message tells you that the error happened at the line 21 in `Program.cs`. You need to find that code line and review it. For example, you can open that code file in the Visual Studio, press Ctrl-G and type 21 in the dialog box.

There is probably another usage of your array in that line, but the value of index in that line is outside the array bounds (less than 0, or more than 9). Find out why and fix.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code, if you are trying to do what you say.  The loop conditions are fine. `(int i = 0; i < userValues.Length-1; i++)` will only run 9 times.  This is not what you are trying to do.  When i references 9 it does not get into the loop as it does not pass the conditions, therefore the loop will run from i = 0, 1, 2, 3... 8 and will increment i to 9 as it exits on iteration 8, therefore not meeting to conditions of the loop.